# Servlet files context in Eclipce WDT

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets, geolocation, eclipse-wtp

My task is to build a network sniffer that translates the captured IPs to their GeoLocations.
I used the MaxMind GeoIP API and their database (GeoIP.dat) to do so and it work just fine (as a simple java application).

Now, my goal is to use this as a tool on a web server the following way.
A dedicated web site (actually with a single page) will make the results (the distribution of the traffic locations) visible on a remote browser.

To be more clear, the sniffer will capture the traffic on some machine's network card and a website (that is located on that machine) will provide a way to view the results from far away.

I thought to implement it using a server side servlet that will refresh the client side page with the results it will get from the sniffer.

The problem is that i have zero experience in web sites development and zero knowledge in the servlets methodology - I am learning on the fly, reading a lot of info.

To be more specific at this moment, I don't know where to place this GeoIP.dat file so it will be accessible from the servlet's context.

I'm using the Eclipse IDE with WDT and Apache Tomcat 6.
No matter where i place the file in the dynamic web project tree, the file isn't found and an exeption arises.
Is it supposed to be in the project tree at all?
To where does Eclipse publish the debugged web site during development?

I hope i was clear enough. If i wasn't please tell me and i'll try to be more accurate.
I'll be very grateful if anyone could direct me a bit.